# why VS 2010 fails to install in windows 7 ?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

Hi I am tryin to install vs2010 on windows 7 and It fails , Here is the error log , can anyone help me ?

```
[09/02/12,17:17:22] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] CRootComponent::Install(): Cannot install; setup files failed verification.
[09/02/12,17:17:22] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_INVALID returned in CRootComponent::Install; the following file is invalid: h:\vs_setup.msi
[09/02/12,17:17:24] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU is not installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:24] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:24] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:24] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Office Developer Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:25] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:26] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:26] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:26] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:26] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:26] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 IntelliTrace (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:26] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:26] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:27] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:27] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:27] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:27] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:27] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:27] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:27] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SharePoint Developer Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:28] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[09/02/12,17:17:28] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x64 was not attempted to be installed.
```

Comment: It doesn't, I installed VS 2010 Ultimate on my Windows 7 without any problems.

Comment: Have you tried: https://connect.microsoft.com/

Comment: @DannyVarod How sshould i use that ?

Comment: @Karamafrooz to search for similar bugs (assuming you have already checked the setup). Maybe there is a user with similar circumstances with a solution. What have you tried? Did you Google this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [09/02/12,17:17:22] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU: [2] ERROR_INSTALL_PACKAGE_INVALID returned in CRootComponent::Install; the following file is invalid: h:\vs_setup.msi

Your installer is corrupt.

Comment: thx , what can I do ? I am trying to install using a iso file, I mounted it to a drive .

Comment: Say that I have verified the file to be correct - how would I determine if the *code* to verify `vs_setup.msi` is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Move your iso to local machine and try to install again

Comment: I axtracted the iso and tried to install it but It did not work

Comment: @Karamafrooz ummm disable virus scanner on your machine, if you got Visual C++ runtimes in your machine remove them and try to install again